# Connect URL in the application settings editor

Tags: facebook, callback

To fix this error, please set your Connect URL in the application settings editor. Once it has been set, users will be redirect to that URL instead of this page after logging in.

How can set THIS URL ??

I am using fb:login-button

if anyone can help me with some details ... appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem and there is simply no such "Connect URL" field in the application settings editor!

Comment: Unfortunately, i didn't. Facebook don update the documentation when the API is updated ... this is to bad. If u managed to solve it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a parameter you can pass in to handle this?

Example, on this page they cite:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

params like registration-url and redirect_uri